# How to check the count of function template instantiations

Tags: c++, templates

How to check the count of function template instantiations?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T f) {}
 
struct Bar {
  void operator()(bool x) {}
};
 
void f1(bool x) {}
 
void f2(bool x) {}
 
int main() {
  foo(f1);
  foo(Bar());
  foo(f2);
  foo([](bool x){});
  foo([](bool x){});
}
```

Comment: What kind of result do you expect to obtain?

Comment: the count of function template foo instantiation

Comment: I guess this is out of curiosity? I don't see any reason why you would want to know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took this as (a kind of) puzzle assuming that OP is asking out of curiosity.

To achieve this, I intend to add something to `template foo()` that is called for each template instance exactly once. The construction of a static instance is an option for this.

The second part of the solution is to let each of these static instances increase a counter. So, I used a class with a static member variable for the static instance whereby the constructor increments that counter.

Et voilà, here we go:

```
#include <iostream>

struct FooCounter {
  static unsigned n;
  FooCounter() { ++n; }
};
unsigned FooCounter::n = 0;

template <typename T>
void foo(T f)
{
  static FooCounter count;
}
 
struct Bar {
  void operator()(bool x) {}
};
 
void f1(bool x) {}
 
void f2(bool x) {}
 
int main() {
  foo(f1);
  foo(Bar());
  foo(f2);
  foo([](bool x){});
  foo([](bool x){});
  std::cout << "Counted " << FooCounter::n << " distinct template instances of foo().\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Counted 4 distinct template instances of foo().
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbbf1b231f268f3f)

---

**Bonus Part:**

`4` matches the number of template instances I expected.
Though, I must admit that I expected the 4 for the wrong reason realizing my mistake on the 2<sup>nd</sup> glance.

- `foo(f1)` and `foo(f2)` share the same template instance because `f1()` and `f2()` have the exact same signature.
- The duplicated call of `foo([](bool x){});` is the one where each counts.
  The reason is that each lambda gets a unique type (generated internally by the compiler). (That they are literally identical is regardless.) Hence, `template foo()` is instanced for each of them.

[**Augmented Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10facbb068d21e2b)

---

Holy black cat...

I've just learnt that this can be even improved to count template instances of `foo()` even before/without they have been called. (It once more proves that nearly everything can be solve by another level of indirection.)

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat for the demo:

```
#include <iostream>

int &FooCounter()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    return counter;
}

template <typename>
struct FooHelper
{
    inline static int count = []{FooCounter()++; return 0;}();
};

template <auto> struct Use {};

template <typename T>
void foo(T f)
{
    Use<&FooHelper<T>::count>{};
}
 
struct Bar {
  void operator()(bool x) {}
};
 
void f1(bool x) {}
 
void f2(bool x) {}

using FooDouble = decltype(foo<double>); // <-- an explicit template instance
// which is never called but counted as well

int main() {
  std::cout << "Counted " << FooCounter() << " distinct template instances of foo().\n";
  foo(f1);
  foo(Bar());
  foo(f2);
  foo([](bool x){});
  foo([](bool x){});
}
```

Output:

```
Counted 5 distinct template instances of foo().
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1598b0576b0e424e)

Please, note that even the never-called template instance `foo<double>()` is counted. (Due to the side-effect in the `FooCounter`, the compiler may not optimize it away even although it is never called.)

---

After having thought a while about this, I got an idea for a serious use case for this: This can be used to automate registration of classes in a factory.

Comment: It seems this only counts instantiations that are called, after they're called.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Correct. (I had no better idea.)

Comment: Here's a possible fix: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da1f32ac7a41e13a

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I edited your approach into my answer (your kindly permission assumed).

Comment: I don't know how you get  5 distinct template instances when you add "using FooDouble = decltype(foo<double>);"  this line, for me it doesn't make any change. Still 4.

Comment: @NusratNuriyev You are right: [Live Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a30eab85ddbf0258). This demo was done on an older version of g++. Running the same demo with the current version results in 4. It seems that template trick is not that reliable...